# Usage of "until" and "unless"

Tags: difference, conjunctions

Is the use of "until" correct in the below context:

> **Until** you do that one role that people recognise you for, you don't become an actor.

And would this be correct:

> **Unless** you do that one role that people recognise you for, you don't become an actor.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

*Until* and *unless* can be used in many of the same places, but they have slightly different meanings.

*Until* refers to the time that something happens, and may be used to imply a chain of cause-and effect.

> I won't make any money *until* I get a job. ➔ I will make some money *when* I get a job.
>
> She didn't return *until* last week.
>
> I'm not going to discuss this with you *until* you calm down.

*Unless* refers to a chain of cause-and-effect without reference to a specific time.

> I won't make any money *unless* I get a job. ➔ I will make some money *if* I get a job.
>
> You can't become a great musician *unless* you practice a lot.
>
> I will go to the beach on Saturday, *unless* it rains.

Since chains of cause-and-effect always move forward in time, these two concepts sometimes overlap.

In your case, both versions of the sentence are correct and mean almost the same thing.

> *Until* you do that one role that people recognise you for, you don't become an actor.
>
> ➔ You only become an actor *when* you do that one role.
>
> *Unless* you do that one role that people recognise you for, you don't become an actor.
>
> ➔ You only become an actor *if* you do that one role.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped.